# Accessing null ArrayList from JSON in Main Activity

Tags: android, json, arraylist

I know this question has been asked a lot but I still can't figure out how on my code. I'm trying to get values out of this block of code:

```
 private void getAnswerKey(){
    class GetAnswerKey extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            JSON_STRING = s;
            showAnswerKey();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String s = rh.sendGetRequest(Configuration.URL_GET_ANSWER);
            return s;
        }
    }
    GetAnswerKey gA = new GetAnswerKey();
    gA.execute();
}


private void showAnswerKey () {
    correctAnswers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Configuration.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);

        for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
            int answerKey = jo.getInt(Configuration.TAG_ANSWERKEY);
            correctAnswers.add(answerKey);
            System.out.println((i + 1) + "a. " + options[correctAnswers.get(i)]); //data are there
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How do I access *correctAnswers* arrayList on my main activity? *correctAnswers* itself isn't empty in this code, but when I tried accessing it on other method, it's null. I've tried passing data to other method. Still return null. I have the arrayList as global variable. Any ideas how??

Comment: Can you provide the entire code? It seems like you're trying to access `correctAnswers` before it's computed.

Comment: @suvojit_007 I declared it in onCreate, that's it.

Comment: post the crash log.

Comment: @KishoreJethava no crash! the problem is that arraylist is null when i try to access it in different method

Comment: post that code where you getting null `correctAnswers` or Full code if possible

Comment: @KishoreJethava https://pastebin.com/WJA9wU3j this is some of the code

Answer (score 0):

Like suvojit_007 might have correctly assumed, you may be attempting to access the arraylist before it is populated..

You can use interfaces. Create your interface...

```
public interface ResponseInterface {
    public void getResponse(String data);
}
```

In your `AsyncTask` declare your interface

```
private ResponseInterface responseInterface;
```

Create a constructor within the `AsyncTask` with the interface as a parameter

```
public GetAnswerKey(ResponseInterface responseInterface) {
     this.responseInterface = responseInterface;
 }
```

Within your `onPostExecute`, call the interface

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    responseInterface.getResponse(s);
}
```

... and finally when executing your `AsyncTask`, do this...

```
new GetAnswerKey(new ResponseInterface() {
        @Override
        public void getResponse(String data) {
           // do whatever you want with your answers here.
           // Also, whatever function that is accessing the 
           // arrayList, call it here, that way you avoid any 
           // possibility of the arrayList being null
        }
}).execute();
```

Comment: what if i wanna access it from onCreate??

Comment: To access it from the onCreate, id suggest you execute the `AsyncTask` within the onCreate (like i showed above) rather that executing it your `getAnswerKey()` function... 
But if there are any other functions that need to consume the result or access the NonNull arraylist, call them from within the `getResponse(String data)` function